# Perl accumulator array for implicit loop one liner? (to perform a sql-like GROUP BY sum)

Tags: perl

I want to sum the following data, grouped by month (my Amazon spending aggregated by month):

INPUT:

```
2016-08     $5
2016-08     $10
2016-09     $7
2016-09     $6
2016-10     $7
2016-10     $5
```

OUTPUT:

```
2016-08     $15
2016-09     $13
2016-10     $12
```

and I've seen a lot of ugly solutions on the web. I want to use the `perl -pe` syntax like I would for regex substitutions (i.e. implicit loop).

Can this be done, perhaps with an "implicit variable" that is an array?

I imagine the command to be something like this:

```
cat mydata.csv | perl -pe 's{(.*)\s*(.*)}{dict[$1] = $1 , dict[$1] += $2 }ge END { print @dict}'
```

**ANSWER**

Remember, in non-strict mode you don't need to declare any variables including arrays. You can just use them as the accepted answer indicates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Perl in the same way you use AWK and refer to the fields in `@F`:

```
perl -alne '$F[1]=~tr/$//d; $tot{$F[0]} += $F[1];
   END { for $d (sort keys %tot) { print "$d\t\$$tot{$d}" } }' mydata.csv
```

Note you have to handle the dollar sign, both stripping it out an adding it back in.

Comment: Bingo, this is what I was looking for. The "what you have" of mine doesn't actually work, it was just a general pattern I was looking for. It looks like the `-ne` part plus `END` is what I was after. Now I need to go back and deconstruct this to understand it and hopefully make further use of it.

Comment: and yes the `| sort` is the final piece of the jigsaw. The power of composability with pipes to the rescue on that.

Comment: Fixed so `sort` isn't needed.

Comment: wow. Actually the dollar part I just left in in the example so you got a better idea what I was trying to do. I would have adapted my code to strip that out.  But your way is shorter.

Comment: Golfed down a bit: `perl -lane'$tot{$F[0]} += substr($F[1],1);
       END { print "$_\t\$$tot{$_}" for sort keys %tot } }'`

Answer (score 1):

The `-n` and `-p` options wrap a `while (<>) { ... }` around the whole program, but we don't really want it around the *whole* thing, so we need to recreate it ourselves (along with `-a` emulation):

```
$ perl -WE 'while (<>) { @F = split; $F[1] =~ s/\$//; $H{$F[0]} += $F[1]; } say "$_ \$$H{$_}" for sort(keys(%H))' data.txt
```

Output:

```
2016-08 $15
2016-09 $13
2016-10 $12
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I thought the `END` keyword got around that problem didn't it? Or am I misunderstanding what that means?